# json_encode fails to encode one of two php arrays - Why?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two php arrays I want to encode to json. 
One succeeds (I get a json array in return) and the other one fails (No output).

This is the one that fails: http://pastebin.com/zyiTuARn

This is the one that succeeds: http://pastebin.com/qHrXKTyn

Can anyone clue me in on why the first one doesn't output anything?

Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: Maybe you try to encode non-utf-8 characters.

Comment: @steven Thanks - Your and AbraCadaver's answers helped me solve it.

Answer (score 3):

The array that failed wasn't UTF-8 encoded.

I solved it by using this neat function:

```
        function utf8_converter($array)
        {
            array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
                if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
                        $item = utf8_encode($item);
                }
            });
            return $array;
        }
```